# I cannot get client side and server side validation to work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have the following forms

```html
<form name="courses">
  <div="requiredfield">
    <input type="text" name="coursename" id="coursename">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" name="submitform1">
</form>
<form name="students">
  <div="requiredfield">
    <input type="text" name="studentfirstname" id="studentfirstname">
  </div>
  <div="requiredfield">
    <input type="text" name="studentlastname" id="studentlastname">
  </div>
  <div="requiredfield">
    <input type="text" name="studentage" id="studentage">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" name="submitform2">
</form>
```

I use this code for client side validation

```js
// this works fine
$('#courses').submit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if ($('#coursename').val() == 0) {
    // error message is appended to the div containing the field
    // the same for the other form and its field
  }
}
```

What does not work is the server side validation

```php
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submitform1'])) {
        if (empty($_POST['coursename'])) {
            $course_mistake = "please fill this field"
        }
    }
?>
```

I have no idea why the server side validation does not work. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form name = "courses" method="post" action="validation.php">
 // Your form fields.
</form>
```

You should specify the method and the name of `php` file in `<form>` , in which your controls will go on `submit` .

See this http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Comment: You can omit `action` and form will be submitted to same page as in where it's located.

Answer (score 0):

**1** You prevent form submitting:

```
$('#courses').submit(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // This prevents form submitting to PHP side
```

If you don't use Ajax (I don't see any code related), than you are note sending data to PHP

**2** `<form name="courses">` means you are using `$_GET` method, but in PHP you expect `$_POST`.
Either add `method="post"` or in PHP use `$_GET`/`$_REQUEST`.

**3** You are not outputting errors nowhere - missing `$course_mistake` processing